# Parse arguments in sequential order (incl. repeated arguments) [.py]

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, command-line-arguments, sequence

I'm writing a function that generates a sequence waveforms, and want to let the user specify the frequency and duration of each sine wave in the sequence.

How can I define a positional argument parser that can take arguments in the following form, which accounts for the order in which each switch is passed?:

```python
waveSequence.py --sine 440 1 --silence 0.5 --sine 110 2
```

(This will generate a 440Hz sine for 1 second, followed by 0.5 seconds of silence, followed by a 110Hz sine for 2 seconds.)

Is it even possible to recycle switches like this?

---

One way around it might be to just read arguments by position. In bash, I could do something like this:

```bash
if [ $1 -eq 'sine' ]; then
    freq=$2
    time=$3
    shift
    shift
    shift
    # Next, continue reading from 4th argument
elif [ $1 -eq 'silence' ]; then
    # no freq, only time
    time=$2
    shift
    shift
else
    # other waveforms
fi
```

How can I shift through the positional arguments in Python?

Comment: Perhaps a command line interface is not the best approach here?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sys.argv` for raw argument strings.

Code:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

```
$ python waveSequence.py --sine 440 1 --silence 0.5 --sine 110 2
['waveSequence.py', '--sine', '440', '1', '--silence', '0.5', '--sine', '110', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, there is no way to make positional `--option` arguments. May be, the way to go is to use keywords with regular positional arguments, e.g.

```
$ waveSequence.py sine-440-1 silence-0.5 sine-110-2
```

Code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description="wave sequence generation")
parser.add_argument("waves", type=str, nargs="+")

args = parser.parse_args()

for arg in args.waves:
    (type, spec) = arg.split("-", 1)
    if type == "sine":
        (freq, duration) = spec.split("-")
        print "Playing sine wave with frequency %s for %ss" % (freq, duration)
    elif type == "silence":
        duration = spec
        print "Silence for %ss" % duration
```

Output:

```
Playing sine wave with frequency 440 for 1s
Silence for 0.5s
Playing sine wave with frequency 110 for 2s
```